# Access nested json file values

Tags: python, json

My .json file contains:

```
"message": [
    {
        "first": [
            "hi",
            "hii"
        ],
        "second": [
            "bye",
            "byee"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want Python to randomly print `hi or hii` and `bye or byee`, `choice` would fit here.

But to use it I firstly need to print the values of `first` and `second`.

My code only prints

```
first
second
```

Here it is:

```
def read_settings(file):
    with open(file, encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        return load(f)

# Read json file
file = read_settings('settings.json')

for i in file['message'][0]:
    print(i)
```

I want it to print

```
hi # or hii
bye # or byee
```

Comment: What's `read_settings`?

Comment: It's a function that reads the json file, one min

Answer (score 0):

Try using `random` module with a list comprehension:

```py
random.choice([x for y in myFile["message"][0] for x in myFile["message"][0][y]])
```

Note that, I have changed the variable you named `file` into `myFile` because `file` is kind of predefined in python.

This function returns a random element of the list `["hi", "hii", "bye", "bye"]`. But if you want to return value of `first` key or `second` key, you can try:

```py
random.choice([myFile["message"][0][x] for x in myFile["message"][0]])
```

This one, actually returns a list. It returns `['hi', 'hii']` or `['bye', 'byee']`

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate through an dictionary like you have (`for i in file['message'][0]:`), it only fetch the keys of that dictionary.
To print the random values wrt the key try using:

```
import random
for key, values in file['message'][0].items():
    print(random.choice(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet

```
for i in file['message'][0]:
    print(i)
```

Just prints the key of the python `dictionary`:

```
{'first': ['hi', 'hii'], 'second': ['bye', 'byee']}
```

In order to get `values` and hence the desired output just modify your code to import random library

```
import random

...
...
...

for i in file['message'][0]:
    values = file['message'][0][i]
    random.choices(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
for option in file['message']:
  for value in option.keys():
    print(option[value][random.randrange(0,2)])
```

`for option in file['message']` -> return 'first' and 'seccond' with its values inside ("hi", "hii" and "bye", "byee")

`for value in option.keys():` -> pick just 'first' and 'second' values

`print(option[value][random.randrange(0,2)])` -> select the "hi" or "hii", (option[0][0] will be "hi"), so select option[0][random value between 0 and 1].

That way you have your values generated randomly.